# How to send a PyDict object from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++

I have a c++ map that I need to send to a python script for processing. I figured that I should put it in a PyDict and then send it. The problem s that my script doesn't receive it correctly

my c++

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Py_Initialize();

  PyObject *import, *attr, *instance, *methodcall, *arg, *tuple;
  PySys_SetPath("./py/");
  import = PyImport_ImportModule("class_test");
  attr = PyObject_GetAttrString(import, "TestMap");
  arg = PyString_FromString("arg from first");
  tuple = PyTuple_Pack(1, arg);
  instance = PyInstance_New(attr, tuple, NULL);

  PyObject *d = PyDict_New();
  PyDict_SetItemString(d, "k", PyInt_FromLong(3000)) ? printf("seting item failed\n") : printf("seting item succeeded\n");

  methodcall = PyObject_CallMethod(instance, "hello", "s", d);

  Py_DECREF(instance);
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

and my simple script

```
class TestMap(CLBase):
  def __init__(self, c):
    self.c = c
    pass
  def hello(self, s):
    print "From python script"
    print s
```

the output is

```
seting item succeeded
From python script
☺
```

so rather than printing the dictionary something like `{"k":3000}` it prints a smiley face

**I would really appreciate an answer using the default python API (using python.h) not any other library**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
methodcall = PyObject_CallMethod(instance, "hello", "s", d);
```

With the `"s"` you're telling it that the argument is a `char*` but it's actually a dictionary (a `PyObject*`). If you use `"O"` it will be correctly interpreted as a `PyObject*`. The format string of `PyObject_CallMethod` is interpreted as per `Py_BuildValue` and so is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue).

The smiley face is just a re-interpretation of whatever is in the memory of the dict as a string.

---

Other than that you should be checking the return values of the Python API functions (`NULL` usually indicates an error) and there look to be some `PyObject`s that you never decref, so you're leaking memory.